# how do I write a working firestore collection group security rule for write/delete

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

either I'm doing something wrong or firestore security rules for collection groups don't seem to be working as intended. The following rule allows me to add a `doc` to a `notes` collection but when I try to read it I get `missing or insufficient permissions`

```
match /{path=**}/notes/{notedoc} {
    allow write: if false;
    allow read: if false;
}
```

I need `request.auth.uid != null` to be able to `read`, `create`, and `update` and only `request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.superadmin == true;` to be able to `delete`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I've simplified the rules above, but the following also allows users to delete notes

```
match /{path=**}/notes/{notedoc} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow delete: if false;
      allow get: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow list: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that throws that permission denied error, and show the index definitely that you made for the collection group query?

Comment: Those first rules reject all read and writes (`if false`), so getting a permission denied there seems expected. Is that not what you're seeing? Or do you somehow expect your code to not be affected by those rules, or to get permission out of them?

Comment: I could not reproduce a collection group rule allowing you to write while it’s set to `false` as you describe. I tested this from the Firebase [rules playground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator) and the web SDK 9. To find exactly what could be going wrong, you should provide as many details as you can, including your full security rules and the exact collection group queries you are running.

Comment: thanks for the comments @ErnestoC - I will try to add more details and make a minimal reproduction

Comment: thanks for the comments @FrankvanPuffelen - I will try to add more details and make a minimal reproduction